# How do I make uWSGI restart when a Python script is modified?

Tags: django, uwsgi

Can't remember where, but I read uWSGI can reload itself like Django development server when a project script is modified. I can't find that in [the docs](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Doc), nor in the internets. How can I do this?

I use Ubuntu 12.04 on my working machines and Debian Squeeze on stage & production server, Django 1.4 and uWSGI 1.2.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Reference: http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Management

If you have started uwsgi with the `--touch-reload=/path/to/special/file/usually/the.ini` option, reloading your uWSGI is a simple matter of touch reloading that file with

`touch /path/to/special/file/usually/the.ini`

And if you want the "autoreload" capability, this is the tip that gets this done:
http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/TipsAndTricks#uWSGIdjangoautoreloadmode

Comment: 11 years later, please note that touch-reload needs a file that has been changed by the app in order to work. In my case, that file is not the ini, but some html file that my Flask app generates.

Answer (score 40):

There is a `py-autoreload=N` option in newer releases. Just set `N` to the frequency (in seconds) of checks (3 is a good value).

Comment: "use only in development" according to [uwsgi docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#py-auto-reload-py-autoreload-python-auto-reload-python-autoreload)

Comment: looks like [touch-reload=/some/file](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#touch-reload) is a safer option

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want lose the django autoreload, register this reload method (i.e: in settings.py):

```
import uwsgi
from uwsgidecorators import timer
from django.utils import autoreload

@timer(3)
def change_code_gracefull_reload(sig):
    if autoreload.code_changed():
        uwsgi.reload()
```

Now if you change your code it will be reloaded.

*Author: Simone Federici*

Comment: This worked perfectly. Also added a conditional so this only gets called in the development environment.

Comment: `autoreload.code_changed` no longer exists.  what should we use in 2021?

Answer (score 1):

uwsgi also allow restart using kill SIGNAL. I use it as below:

```
# ps -efa | grep uwsgi | grep prod
app  13390 13383  0 07:40 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/app_prod.ini
app  13417 13390  0 07:40 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/app_prod.ini
app  13419 13390  0 07:40 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/app_prod.ini
# kill -HUP 13390
```

If you run same command, you will see child procs pid will be changed as they are re-spawned by master. Also check uwsgi config for master/worker proc counts. This method is easy to integrate with ansible or other automation tools so goes easy to for remote use.

This doesn't need your original proc to be started with --touch-reload.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [docs](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html) to make uWSGI gracefully restart.

```
# using kill to send the signal
kill -HUP `cat /tmp/project-master.pid`
# or the convenience option --reload
uwsgi --reload /tmp/project-master.pid
# or if uwsgi was started with touch-reload=/tmp/somefile
touch /tmp/somefile
```